# Messenger account linking works on mobile but not on desktop

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm developing a Messenger bot and my use case requires me to [link an account](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/account-linking).
I was able to setup this, but I realized that the linking process doesn't work when the *account linking URL* is opened on browser. Though, it actually seems fine if opened on Messenger app.

According to the docs, there are two parameters appended on the account linking URL automatically: (a) account_linking_token and (b) redirect_uri.

Based on my test, the parameters are provided on Messenger app, but not on browser which causes it to fail.

I'll be grateful for any help you can provide and explanation on why this happen. Is account linking only works on mobile phone? Or is there something that I'm missing?